# StatusBar dark icons on API < 23

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I'm creating an Activity and I want to change the color of the StatusBar icons to gray.

I'm already using this to cause the effect I want:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

But this only works from the API 23 and above.

What is the best way to do this for devices with API < 23?